# People love, but hate to see me

Tags: riddle

> When I'm around, better stay inside
>
> People love, but hate to see me;
>
> My task is to hide
>
> As my quest is for your life to be the key

**What am I?**

Comment: What about a hint, now?

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> The Sun

As

> Better to stay inside when it's sunny, people love The Sun but not to see it, The Sun hides behind clouds, so it keeps helping the life (esp. of the plants).

Comment: That's a great answer! +1, but it's not what I was thinking about

Answer (score 2):

My guess is

> Lightning/electricity

When I'm around, better stay inside

> Don't want to get caught out in a lightning storm.

People love, but hate to see me;

> Personally I either love or hate to see a lightning storm... it all depends on how far away it is! It's great to look at when it's at a good distance, but I'm not a fan when it strikes a tree in the yard.

My task is too hide
As my quest is for your life to be the key

> We can see manifestations of electricity in the arcs of lightning or shorted wires, but electricity in and of itself is not visible to the naked eye. Electricity can be a killer for sure. And I attribute the 'key' reference to Ben Franklin's experiments.

Answer (score 2):

A bit gruesome but might you be a

> murderer

When I'm around, better stay inside

> better not go outside when their's one reported in your neighbourhood

People love, but hate to see me;

> It can be anyone, someone close to you that you might care about, but you would hate that person of you knew the truth

My task is to hide

> His task is to stay undetected for others

As my quest is for your life to be the key

> The key for being a murderer would be other peoples lives.

Answer (score 1):

You may be ...

> the rain.

*When I'm around, better stay inside*

> If you don't want to get wet, you better stay inside or somewhere where you're protected from the rain.

*People love, but hate to see me;*

> People (especially children) like the rain. And e.g. farmers **need** rain for their plants. However, usually you can't go outside doing sports or so and thus you hate to see it raining. Furthermore, raining may make you feel weak/depressed.

*My task is to hide*

> However, I can't really use the third sentence. That's not a good sign, but it's worth a try ... :)
>  (Why should the rain try to hide?)

*As my quest is for your life to be the key*

> Water (and therefore, raining as natural source of water) is the key of all life on earth.